# AttributeError: X object has no attribute X

Tags: python, tkinter

Vean, tengo un error que cuando inicio la app que dice:

```
***AttributeError: 'PanelNavegation' object has no attribute 'balace_windows'***.
```

Este error ocurre cuando doy "click" por ejemplo, en el botón registrar me sale el error de balance, y si doy click primero en balance me sale error de registro y así sucesivamente con los demás botones. Alguien sabe el porque se eso?

También me pasa que cuando inicio el programa y el primer "click" que doy no importa el botón, que sea no me muestra el frame de una, tengo que dar "click" en otro botón y luego volver al botón que di "click" primeramente para que me muestre el frame y así con todos los botones.

Una breve explicación la clase ***class PanelNavegation(ctk.CTkFrame)***: esta contiene 6 botones que a su vez tiene 2 métodos uno para que cuando el usuario de "click" en un boton este quede iluminado (indicandole al usuario que está en ese frame) el otro método es el evento del botón que se coloca en la config de los botones (command).

[![Clase PanelNavegation][1]][1]
[![Continuacion clase PanelNavegation][2]][2]
[![Clase Balance_Windows. Esta en un modulo aparte][3]][3]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWaF8.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rlbW.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw0fA.png

[image: Aplicacion de escritorio]

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
import datetime as dt
from balance_gui import Balance_Windows
from registrar_gui import Registrar_Windows
from eliminar_gui import Eliminar_Windows
from visualizar_gui import Visualizar_Windows
from pendientes_gui import Pendientes_Windows
from configuracion_gui import Configuracion_Windows

class App(ctk.CTk): 
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        
        #CONFIG MAIN WINDOWS
        self.geometry("1200x800")
        self.title("PRUEBA")
        self.resizable(False,False)
        self.configure(fg_color="#FCF8E8")
        
        ##CONFIG GRID
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=0)  # Set the weight of the first row to 0, so the FrameHeader doesn't fill the entire row
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=2)  # Set the weight of the second row to 1, so the MyFrame fills the remaining space  
                                
        #instanciate classes
        self.header = FrameHeader(self)  # Add the FrameHeader to the top row
        self.header.grid(row=0, column=0,pady=5,padx=2, sticky="ew") # Set sticky to "we" to make the FrameHeader fill the entire row
        
        self.Panel_Navegation = PanelNavegation(self)  # Add the panel to the second row
        self.Panel_Navegation.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="wens",pady=1,padx=2,)
        
                                 
class FrameHeader(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master,*args,**kwargs,):  
        super().__init__(master,*args,**kwargs,height=30,fg_color="#BF9270", border_color="black",border_width=3)
        
        #EXPORT LOGO
        img = tk.PhotoImage(file="Imagenes/logo.png").subsample(15, 15)

        self.grid_columnconfigure((0,2), weight=1)  # Agregar una columna adicional y configurarla para que tenga un peso de 1
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
        
        ##TITLE FIRST FRAME TOP. MAIN WINDOWS
        self.lblheader = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="SISTEMA DE SEGUIMIENTO Y GESTIÓN DE SALUD MENTAL",font=("Helvetica",14,"bold"), width=20,image=img,compound="left")
        self.lblheader.grid(row=0, column=1,  pady=5, sticky="nsew",columnspan=2)  # Mover el label del titulo a la columna central
        
        self.hora_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, font=("Helvetica", 12,"bold"),text_color="#FCE22A")
        self.hora_label.place(x=1110,y=13) # Mover el label de la hora a la columna de la derecha
        self.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

        # Actualizar la hora cada segundo
        self.actualizar_hora()
        
        #METODO PARA LA HORA
    def actualizar_hora(self):
        ahora = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S %p")
        self.hora_label.configure(text=ahora)
        self.hora_label.after(1000, self.actualizar_hora)
        
class PanelNavegation(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master,*args,**kwargs,):
        super().__init__(master,*args,**kwargs, height=50,fg_color="#BF9270",border_color="black",border_width=3)
               
        #CONFIG GRID FRAME
        self.columnconfigure((0,1,2,3,4), weight=1)        
        self.rowconfigure((0,1,2),weight=1)

        #EXPORT IMG
        img1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="Imagenes/balance.png").subsample(15, 15)
        img2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="Imagenes/registrar.png").subsample(15, 15)
        img3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="Imagenes/eliminar.png").subsample(15, 15)
        img4 = tk.PhotoImage(file="Imagenes/visualizar.png").subsample(15, 15)
        img5 = tk.PhotoImage(file="Imagenes/pendientes.png").subsample(15, 15)
        img6 = tk.PhotoImage(file="Imagenes/configuraciones.png").subsample(15, 15)
        
        #CREATE BTN AND GRID
        self.btn_BALANCE = ctk.CTkButton(self,fg_color="#85CDFD", font=("Helvetica",18,"bold"),text_color="#001253", text="BALANCE", image=img1, compound="left",width=150,border_color="black",corner_radius=50,border_width=3,command=self.balance_button_event)
        self.btn_BALANCE.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="we")
        
        self.btn_REGISTRAR = ctk.CTkButton(self,fg_color="#85CDFD", font=("Helvetica",18,"bold"),text_color="#001253", text="REGISTRAR", image=img2, compound="left",width=150,border_color="black",corner_radius=50,border_width=3,command=self.registrar_button_event)
        self.btn_REGISTRAR.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="we")
        
        self.btn_ELIMINAR = ctk.CTkButton(self,fg_color="#85CDFD", font=("Helvetica",18,"bold"),text_color="#001253", text="ELIMINAR", image=img3, compound="left",width=150,border_color="black",corner_radius=50,border_width=3,command=self.eliminar_button_event)
        self.btn_ELIMINAR.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="we")
                
        self.btn_VISUALIZAR = ctk.CTkButton(self,fg_color="#85CDFD", font=("Helvetica",18,"bold"),text_color="#001253", text="VISUALIZAR",image=img4, compound="left",width=150,border_color="black",corner_radius=50,border_width=3,command=self.visualizar_button_event)
        self.btn_VISUALIZAR.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="we")
       
        self.btn_PENDIENTES = ctk.CTkButton(self,fg_color="#85CDFD", font=("Helvetica",18,"bold"),text_color="#001253", text="PENDIENTES",image=img5, compound="left",width=150,border_color="black",corner_radius=50,border_width=3,command=self.pendientes_button_event)
        self.btn_PENDIENTES.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="we")
        
        self.btn_CONFIGURACIÓN = ctk.CTkButton(self,fg_color="#85CDFD", font=("Helvetica",18,"bold"),text_color="#001253", text="CONFIGURACIÓN",image=img6, compound="left",width=150,border_color="black",corner_radius=50,border_width=3,command=self.configuracion_button_event)
        self.btn_CONFIGURACIÓN.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="we")              
                                           
    def select_frame_by_name(self,name):
        # set button color for selected button
        self.btn_BALANCE.configure(fg_color="yellow" if name == "BALANCE" else "#85CDFD")
        self.btn_REGISTRAR.configure(fg_color="yellow" if name == "REGISTRAR" else "#85CDFD")
        self.btn_VISUALIZAR.configure(fg_color="yellow" if name == "VISUALIZAR" else "#85CDFD")
        self.btn_PENDIENTES.configure(fg_color="yellow" if name == "PENDIENTES" else "#85CDFD")
        self.btn_ELIMINAR.configure(fg_color="yellow" if name == "ELIMINAR" else "#85CDFD")
        self.btn_CONFIGURACIÓN.configure(fg_color="yellow" if name == "CONFIGURACION" else "#85CDFD")

        # show selected frame
        if name == "BALANCE":
            self.balance_windows = Balance_Windows(self.master)
            self.balance_windows.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="news",padx=5,pady=5)
        else:
            self.balance_windows.forget()       
        if name == "REGISTRAR":
            self.registrar_windows = Registrar_Windows(self.master)
            self.registrar_windows.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="news",padx=5,pady=5)
        else:
            self.registrar_windows.forget()           
        if name == "VISUALIZAR":
            self.visualizar_windows = Visualizar_Windows(self.master)
            #self.visualizar_windows.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="news",padx=5,pady=5)
        else:
            self.visualizar_windows.forget()
        if name == "ELIMINAR":
            self.eliminar_windows = Eliminar_Windows(self.master)
            #self.eliminar_windows.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="news",padx=5,pady=5)
        else:
            self.eliminar_windows.forget()
        if name == "PENDIENTES":
            self.pendientes_windows = Pendientes_Windows(self.master)
            #self.pendientes_windows.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="news",padx=5,pady=5)
        else:
            self.pendientes_windows.forget()      
        if name == "CONFIGURACION":
            self.configuracion_windows = Configuracion_Windows(self.master)
            #self.configuracion_windows.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="news",padx=5,pady=5)
        else:
            self.configuracion_windows.forget()     
            
    ##FUNCIONES EVENTO QUE SE LLAMARAN DESDE EL BOTON = COMMAND           
    def balance_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("BALANCE")
         
    def registrar_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("REGISTRAR")
   
    def eliminar_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("ELIMINAR")
       
    def visualizar_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("VISUALIZAR")
    
    def pendientes_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("PENDIENTES")
        
    def configuracion_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("CONFIGURACION")   
                                                                                           
app = App()
app.mainloop()

import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk

**MODULO 2**

class Balance_Windows(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master,*args,**kwargs, fg_color="#DDDDDD",border_color="black",border_width=3)
        
        
        #config grid
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure((0,1),weight=0)
         
        self.frameheader = ctk.CTkFrame(self,height=40,fg_color="#537FE7",border_color="black",border_width=3)
        self.frameheader.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="news",padx=5,pady=5,columnspan=2)
                
        self.lbltittle = ctk.CTkLabel(self.frameheader,text="BALANCE",font=("Roboto",20,"bold"),height=5,width=5)
        self.lbltittle.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
        
        self.entrysearch = ctk.CTkEntry(self,placeholder_text="Click here for more information",height=30,corner_radius=10)
        self.entrysearch.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="new",padx=10,pady=10)

        self.btn_search = ctk.CTkButton(self,text="SEARCH",height=30)
        self.btn_search.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="ne",padx=10,pady=10)
```

Comment: Sin ver el código, casi seguro que te has debido dejar una `'n'` al escribir `'balace_windows'`.

Comment: Tambien pense que era eso, pero despues lo acomode y tambien quedo igual

Comment: En el error que se ve en la imagen sale otro atributo del que pones inicialmente. Te dice que no existe `registrar_windows`. En la clase `PanelNavegacion` deberías crear todos los atributos en el constructor `__init__()`, pero hay atributos que estás creando en el `select_frame_by_frame()`, donde **hay atributos que usas antes de definirlos**, y de ahí el error. Tienes que reescribir el código para que todos los atributos estén definidos antes de usarlos.